# Sending a string to google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to know is there a way to send a request string (ex. "shoe stores", "pizza hut", "post office", etc.) to the google maps app and have it do the work for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `geo:0,0?q=business+near+city` `Uri` syntax [documented (lightly) here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html).